# The set $(A \cap B^c)^c\cup (B\cap C)$ is equal to

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The options are

A) $A^c\cup B\cup C$

B) $A^c\cup B$

C) $A^c\cup B^c$

D) $A\cup B^c$

I have thought a lot on this problem but I just can’t figure out how to begin. It would be helpful if I get an answer that serves as an evaluative starting point so that I can solve the rest.

Comment: Make a Venn-diagram.

Comment: Solved it with a vent diagram. Thanks a lot. Although I don’t understand how we can solve it with de Morgan’s law.

Comment: $(A∩B^c )^c ∪ (B∩C)  = (A^c ∪B) ∪ (B∩C)$ by De Morgan. ANd it is equal to $(A^c ∪ B ∪ B) ∩ (A^c ∪ B ∪ C)$ by Distributivity. But $(A^c ∪ B ∪ B) = (A^c ∪ B)$.

Comment: Thus, we are left with $(A^c ∪ B) ∩(A^c ∪ B ∪ C)$. But the left part is a subset of the right one and when $X \subseteq Y$ we have that $X \cap Y=X$. Thus, the result will be : b)  $(A^c ∪ B)$.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

$$(A \cap B^c)^c\cup (B\cap C)=(A^c \cup B)\cup (B\cap C)=$$

$$((A^c \cup B)\cup B) \cap ((A^c \cup B)\cup C)=$$

$$(A^c \cup B) \cap ((A^c \cup B)\cup C)=(A^c \cup B)$$

Thus the correct choice is (B)

Answer (score 1):

Both comments from Floris and Mauro are useful. The complement of $A \cap B^c$ is $A^c \cup B$, which you can derive from De Morgan's Laws or from drawing a Venn diagram and inferring. If $B \cap C = \emptyset$ - $B$ and $C$ are disjoint - then you just have $A^c \cup B$. And if $B$ and $C$ are not disjoint, then $B \cap C$ is at most a subset of $B$. In this case, you also have $A^c \cup B$. Thus, this should be your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use De Morgan's laws

$(A\cap B^c)^c=A^c\cup (B^c)^c=A^c\cup B$, so
$$(A \cap B^c)^c\cup (B\cap C)=A^c\cup B\cup(B\cap C)$$
and observe $B\cap C\subset B$.

Comment: I think you mean $B\cap C \subseteq B$

Comment: Yes. For me, strict inclusion is denoted $\subsetneq$.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who helped. Here is the Venn diagram for this question, to anyone who might find this useful in the future [image]